# Storing object relationship using IndexedDB

Tags: html, indexeddb, persistent-object-store

I am trying to learning HTML5's IndexedDB with mozilla' tutorial [Using Indexed DB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB).

I understand that IndexedDB is object store implementation. But all the examples I tried, they are storing simple objects with key:value pairs. But how would I save a nested or hierarchical objects? For example parent object and have a list of child objects. What is the best way to deal with complex object structures into Indexed DB?

I know the OOPS representation or XML representation of parent-child objects.
How would I achieve it in IndexedDB? Any tutorial source will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> they are only storing key:value pairs. But how would I save a nested object?

What is nested object? You can store any object that can represent by JSON (or more correctly serializable by structured cloning algorithm). Is that nested object? You can convert any OOPS into JSON and get it back through its construction. For XML, just store serialized string format.

If you refer relationship, it is different question. I have write a bit [about IndexedDB relationship](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/schema.html). Modeling a relaionship in IndexedDB is not a problem. In fact, it support very well.

Comment: The link is no longer valid.